# Подсчитать количество вхождений подстроки в строке. И строка, и подстрока вводятся пользователем

Tags: c, строки, char

Если строку и подстроку прописывать в команде, то все работает, если строку и подстроку вводит пользователь то ничего не работает(((((9

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);
    char *sp=str1;
    int i=0;
    while((sp=strstr(sp,str2))!=NULL)
    {
        i++;
        sp+=strlen(str2);               
    }   
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `fgets` читает строку *вместе с завершающим символом `\n`*. Вот у вас ничего и не работает...

Допишите

```
if (str1[strlen(str1)-1] == '\n') str1[strlen(str1)-1] = 0;
if (str2[strlen(str2)-1] == '\n') str2[strlen(str2)-1] = 0;
```

после чтения строк и до начала поиска...